# Калькулятор на python с tkinter.

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

numbers = Entry(root, width = 2)
number2 = Entry(root, width = 2)
key_plus = Button(text = "+")
key_minus = Button(text = "-")
key_multiply = Button(text = "*")
key_divon = Button(text = ":")
Claculete = Button(text = "calculte")
output = Label(width = 10)




def plusnumes():

Get_number1 = numbers.get()
Get_number2 = number2.get()
dm =(str(Get_number2))
dm1 =(str(Get_number2))
dm2 = (int(Get_number2))
dm3 =(int(Get_number2))
result = dm2 + dm3
z1 = (str(result))
output['text'] = (z1)




#algoritam
key_plus.bind('<Button-1>',plusnumes)
key_minus.bind('<Button-1>',)
key_multiply.bind('<Button-1>',)
key_divon.bind('<Button-1>',)






#visualzite
numbers.pack(),number2.pack()
Claculete.pack()
output.pack()
key_plus.pack()
key_minus.pack()
key_multiply.pack()
key_divon.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Программа запускается нормально но когда я пытаюсь использовать функцию 
plusnumes() выводится Вот это ошибка

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
```

TypeError: plusnumes() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вообще при созданиии калькулятора удобно бользоваться стеком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback`и созданы для реагирования на какие-то события (events). Поэтому обычно они **принимают 1 аргумент**:

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events)

```
def bind(self, sequence, func, add=''):
```

> **func** is a Python function, taking one argument, to be invoked when the
>   event occurs. **An Event instance will be passed as the argument**.
>   (Functions deployed this way are commonly known as callbacks.)

---

У вас же колбэк `plusnumes()` принимает 0 аргументов. Для исправления ошибки достаточно добавить в `plusnumes` 1 аргумент, даже если вы не будете использовать этот аргумент - он все равно необходим:

```
def plusnumes(event):
    Get_number1 = numbers.get()
    Get_number2 = number2.get()
    dm =(str(Get_number2))
    dm1 =(str(Get_number2))
    dm2 = (int(Get_number2))
    dm3 =(int(Get_number2))
    result = dm2 + dm3
    z1 = (str(result))
    output['text'] = (z1)
```